# Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmap in Oreo

Tags: android

```
LinearLayout llQRCodeShare;
try {
    llQRCodeShare.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    llQRCodeShare.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = llQRCodeShare.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b);
    llQRCodeShare.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    LogUtil.e(TAG, e.getMessage());    //Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmap
}
```

when execute the code`"llQRCodeShare.getDrawingCache()"`,throws the exception,

```
Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmap
```

on the android8.0.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

just make the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` under `Application` tag

Comment: it should be set to "false"

Comment: It doesn't work on Android 13.

Answer (score 3):

disable [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) either for the whole `Activity`:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

or for that one particular `View`:

```
llQRCodeShare.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Android 13.